# If all eigenvalues of $A \in \operatorname{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ are rational, then they are integers.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> How to show that if $A$ is a $2\times 2$ matrix with all integer entries and all eigenvalues are in $\mathbb{Q}$, then all eigenvalue are integers?

I cannot find why eigenvalues in $\mathbb{Q}$, in this case, will precisely belong to $\mathbb{Z}$?

What is the proof?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem that says a monic polynomial with integer coefficients cannot have rational roots that are not integers?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is monic of degree two, has integer entries, and rational roots...

Comment: how? please explain in answer not in comment spaceisdarkgreen

Answer (score 2):

This follows from the rational root theorem, which implies that any rational root of a polynomial with integer coefficients and leading coefficient one is an integer. The characteristic polynomial of the matrix is a polynomial that meets this criterion.

This actually implies the result for an $n\times n$ matrix, not just a $2\times 2.$ So perhaps they want you to give a more direct proof of the special case. If the characteristic polynomial is $ \lambda^2 + b\lambda + c,$ the roots are $$ \lambda = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4c}}{2}.$$ If these are to be rational, we need $b^2-4c$ to be a perfect square, since it is known that the square root of an integer is either irrational or an integer. (And thus $\sqrt{b^2-4c}$ is an integer.)

Can you show that $-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4c}$ is always even? I suggest splitting it up into the case where $b$ is even and odd.

Comment: what is the case when (b^2-4*a*c)^(1/2) is irrotational? spaceisdarkgreen

Comment: and how to show b^2>=4*c?

Comment: In those cases the solution won’t be rational... you don’t have to worry about them

Comment: what is the exact theorem says? then we cannot say any monic polynomial with integer cofficient has roots in integer.. then could be anhthing.. then what is the specility we have here?

Comment: yes I'm able to show what may be "b", numeretor always is even integer whenever the sq. root gives us a perfect squre

Comment: It says the same thing the premise of your question says. Any *rational* root must be an integer. There can be irrational roots or integer roots, no roots that are both rational and non-integer.

Comment: ok.. that I get it.. but my question when b^2<4*c. then the root will precisely be complex.. for eg. take the eq x^2+x+2=0,here the polynomial is monic & with integer co efficient. but the roots are complex

Comment: Non-real complex numbers are irrational. As I said, the equation may have irrational roots, but who cares? You only need to show if the root is rational then it is an integer.

Comment: thanks a lot. i got it